# Postgres inplace PITR (point in time recovery) or rollback

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres 12.x database (that is cloud hosted).  This particular database instance is a nightly copy of production.  That is used for debugging etc ...

But during the debugging process we might want to roll it back to the time that it was created.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

I imagine like some uber transaction, that I can rollback to.  Is this crazy-talk -- or will postgres continue to amaze me.

Comment: Might be worth providing some more specifics. Note Aurora provides a [cluster-level "snapshot" feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshotCluster.html), but this assumes your cloud hosting provider is AWS.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such facility in PostgreSQL but maybe a [template database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html) could help.

Create the template database as a copy of the production system. Then, whenever you need a test database, clone it with

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb TEMPLATE templatedb;
```

Comment: Note this is largely equivalent to drop/create/restore from a pg_dump file.

Comment: @PeterVandivier No, it is much faster, because the file are copied.